# Use regular expression in linux bash to change output filename

Tags: regex, linux, r, bash

I have downloaded a few epub files and I need to convert them to epub again so that my ebook reader can read them.

I can do conversion in batch fairly easily using R as below:

```
setwd('~/Downloads/pubmed')
epub.files = list.files('./',full.names = TRUE,pattern = 'epub$')
for (loop in (1:length(epub.files))) {
  command = paste('ebook-convert ',
                  epub.files[loop],
                  gsub('\\.epub','.mod.epub',epub.files[loop]))
  system(command)
}
```

But I don't know how to do it using linux bash, I don't know: i) how to assign a variable within a for-loop, and ii) how to use regular expression to replace string in bash.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [bash's parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
for i in *.epub; do 
    ebook-convert ${i} ${i/%.epub/.mod.epub}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and `sed`:

```
cd ~/Downloads/pubmed
for f in $(find . -regex .*epub\$); do
  ebook-convert $f $(echo $f | sed 's/\.epub/.mod.epub/')
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what ebook-convert is, but if you're trying to rename the files, try the following. Paste it into a file with the .sh extension (to signify a shell script) and make sure it is executable (chmod +x your-file.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=~/Downloads/pubmed/*.epub
for f in $FILES
do
  # $f stores the current file name, =~ is the regex operator
  # only rename non-modified epub files
  if [[ ! "$f" =~ \.mod\.epub$ ]]
  then
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    # take action on each file
    mv $f "${f%.*}".mod.epub
  fi
done
```

You will need bash version 3 or greater for regex support. This can be implemented w/o regular expression as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel) in combination with find:

```
find ~/Downloads/pubmed -name '*.epub' | parallel --gnu ebook-convert {} {.}.mod.epub
```

It should be available on most distributions and may have speed advantages over an ordinary loop if you process a large number of files. Although speed was not part of the original question...